# Multiple Pdf Viewer Add Same Page Via Vue Pdf App Component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js, vuex

I want to show two different pdf file (pdf and pdf2) on same page via one component.
When I try to like below, the second pdf file not shown in the page.  Do you have any suggestion

```
  <div id="app">
      <vue-pdf-app style="height: 50vh;" :pdf="pdf" :config="config"></vue-pdf-app>
      <vue-pdf-app style="height: 50vh;" :pdf="pdf2" :config="config"></vue-pdf-app>
    </div>
```

And here is my javascript codes.

```
new Vue({
  components: {
    VuePdfApp: window["vue-pdf-app"]
  },
  data() {
    return {
      config: {
        toolbar: {
          toolbarViewerLeft: { findbar: false }
        }
      },
      pdf: getPdf(),
      pdf2: getPdf()
    };
  }
}).$mount("#app");

function getPdf() {
  const pdf2 =" base 64 string pdf";
  
  const pdf = "base 64 string pdf1 ";

  return base64ToArrayBuffer(pdf);
}

function base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
  var binary_string = window.atob(base64);
  var len = binary_string.length;
  var bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    bytes[i] = binary_string.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return bytes.buffer;
}
```

Here is my code on codepen
https://codepen.io/canbeywas/pen/yLMpEBg

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by slightly modifying your code like this:

```
new Vue({
  components: {
    VuePdfApp: window["vue-pdf-app"]
  },
  data() {
    return {
      config: {
        toolbar: {
          toolbarViewerLeft: { findbar: false }
        }
      },
      pdf: getPdf(),
      pdf2: getPdf2()
    };
  }
}).$mount("#app");

function getPdf() {
  const pdf = "base 64 string pdf1 ";

  return base64ToArrayBuffer(pdf);
}

function getPdf2() {
  const pdf = "base 64 string pdf2 ";

  return base64ToArrayBuffer(pdf);
}

function base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
  var binary_string = window.atob(base64);
  var len = binary_string.length;
  var bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    bytes[i] = binary_string.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return bytes.buffer;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but thats not work :(  Can you show me the working version on "codepen.io" if ist possible. Thank you again.